# How does the slope at Lord's aid swing bowling?

Tags: cricket, venues

I have heard that the slope at Lord's runs down from Nursery end (media centre) to the Pavilion end with a height of around 8 feet.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Cricket_Ground) mentions that the slope aids in-swing from one end and out-swing from the other.

What's the physics behind this? What has the slope to do with the ball swinging?

Answer (score 4):

The slope actually runs across the ground, not down it as you suggest - so the ground at one side of the Pavilion is noticeably higher than the other.

This does aid with moving the ball, but off the pitch (seam) rather than through the air (swing). Bowlers from the Pavilion end can move the ball into a right-handed batsman more easily, and vice versa from the Nursery end.

As can be seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you referred :

> the slope at Lord's runs down from Nursery end (media centre) to the Pavilion end with a height of around 8 feet

---

At the **Pavilion End** when bowling to a right-hander, the ball slides down the slope going further away from the bat than you would naturally expect.

It goes further down the leg side to a left-hander than it would on a flat ground.

The converse occurs at the **Nursery End**.

**[This article](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-india-2014/content/story/761777.html)** explains what Bhuvaneshwar Kumar did to utilize the slope and **[this article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/columnists/geoffreyboycott/2383325/Harmisons-seamers-hold-key-to-exploiting-Lords-slope.html)** referring Steve Harmison.

Answer (score -1):

The Lords slope can't possibly affect the way a ball moves on the pitch. The slope is about 1 in 50 and the amount of contact a ball makes with the surface is minuscule. The movement is all down to the skill of the bowler.

Comment: The question is about swing bowling.  Your answer refers to the effect on spin bowling.